# Angular ng-repeat button losing event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an `ng-repeat` setup with a socket service that updates a list of data. This is happening quite often, less than a second. I have some buttons on this list with `ng-click` events. For example:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="callFunc()">
    <i class="fa fa-gears"></i>
</button>
```

I notice that sometimes when I click nothing happens and I'm guessing this has something to do with the digest cycle and at that particular moment of the click there is a redraw with the icon there but the events not binded yet.

The list is 90% the same but is dynamic in the items on the list so I can't just update values within each item themselves.

It seems to happen quite often enough say around every sixth click, is there a way around this issue?

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/4195/ Click on the buttons enough times and you'll eventually see a miss fire where the alert will not trigger.

Comment: Your code isn't enough to understand your issue. Could you post a fiddle ?

Comment: show entire layout including ng-repeat

Comment: Ok, added jsfiddle... if you click on the buttons enough times you should hopefully see the miss fire within five to ten tries.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your question
But:
If your ng-repeat is in a directive (that means your template in your directive contains ng-repeat) , for every manupulation to $scope , you must use $apply

Generally , in directives , every attempt to manupulate $scope , will need $apply

Let us see your codes to help you, your information is not sufficient

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer, there is an option in `ng-repeat` called `track by`.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat